# Order of addition in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, addition

In what order does Java add up the numbers `a + b + c`?
Is it `a + (b + c)` or `(a + b) + c`?

I just learned how floating point representation works and finished an exercise which explained that if `a, b, c` are `float`s, they might yield a different result when added up in the different ways I wrote above.
That left me wondering which way Java actually does it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The addition operator is left associative, meaning that `a + b + c` is evaluated the same as `(a + b) + c`.

The [JLS, Section 15.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18), states:

> The additive operators have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).

Answer (score 3):

[Left to right (jls-15.18)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) unless you add parenthesis to alter the order of evaluation.

```
static int a() {
    System.out.println("a");
    return 1;
}

static int b() {
    System.out.println("b");
    return 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(a() + b());
}
```

Output is

```
a
b
2
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of `a + b + c` is that of `(a + b) + c` (left associativity).